# Switching between using multiple adapters for a single recyclerview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Can I utilize multiple adapters for my recyclerview wherein I can switch between using one of them to populate my recyclerview?
That is given adapter A populating my recyclerview,I can stop it and use adapter B to repopulate the recyclerview.

Comment: have you tried it ? could you please include what you're struggling with ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Just use RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) with the new adapter